# Formula Works Fine for Just Some Data(not All)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[my file here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=78539964812829898235)

In the attached file, formulas work perfectly for several first customer ids but fail at a point toward the end of the list of customer ids. For example on sheet 2 in cell B2 when you enter customer id "8010001", all requests related to this customer are fetched from sheet 1. Then, if you then make a cell containing a request id(in this case 8234276) active and press "List Policy" button all policies related to this request id are fetched form sheet 1. But this procedure fails for example for customer ids like 8010112, 8010198 ... Even for customer id 8010093 doesn't work completely. You can try it.

Comment: Can you explain the role of the condition `(C1=Sheet1!$J$2:$J$122)` in your formula? As you will copy down the formula, it will compare empty column with the Sheet1 Column J entries.

Comment: Value of c1 is always 1 , the condition is here to list only unique request ids.

Comment: As you will copy down it will not remain C1. It should be `$C$1`.

Comment: It is C1 for all cells, take a look

Comment: Indeed, take a look at my answer and see if it helps your situation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sheet 2 cell B2 (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER) following formula:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$E$1:$E$122,SMALL(IF($C$1&$B$1=Sheet1!$J$1:$J$122&Sheet1!$A$1:$A$122,ROW(Sheet1!$E$1:$E$122),"a"),ROWS($A$1:A1))),"")`

Copy down.

In Sheet 2 cell I2 (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER) following **edited** formula:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$D$1:$D$122,SMALL(IF($C$1&$A$1=Sheet1!$K$1:$K$122&Sheet1!$E$1:$E$122,ROW(Sheet1!$D$1:$D$122),"a"),ROWS($A$1:A1))),"")`

Copy down.

You should get correct results.

**EDIT2**

Explanation for SMALL(IF portion

`$C$1&$B$1` - Simple Concatenation of two cells which is then used to compare with the complete concatenated array from sheet 1 i.e. `Sheet1!$J$1:$J$122&Sheet1!$A$1:$A$122` which results in array of Boolean results `{TRUE,FALSE,TRUE...}`.

If condition is `TRUE` then IF formula returns `ROW(Sheet1!$D$1:$D$122)` which evaluates the row number. In case of `FALSE` result it returns a string `"a"` which results in an error for `SMALL` formula. Ultimate resultant array looks like `{1,"a",3....}`.

Now using `SMALL` we use numeric results one by one. In first cell, `ROWS($A$1:A1)` evaluates to 1 and as we copy it down it generates subsequent numbers like 2,3,4,5 etc. Thus we pick one result at a time from above IF construct.

You can use Formula Evaluate to see the demonstration on small dataset to understand better.

Comment: @FighterJet See here implemented file https://www.dropbox.com/s/8fcyz60ckjd5nl6/stackoverflow_47950789.xlsm?dl=0. Let me know which results are incorrect.

Comment: Yes, It works!! thank you. But it needs some modifications. You ignored the role of "List policy" button which shows policies only for the selected request(active cell). When you enter the customer id, the formula should not automatically list all policies. Enter for example customer id 8010194. Could you make these modifications and re-upload it?

Comment: Ah, I see the requirement now. So you basically list the request IDs in column B using first formula and then get the result copied to cell A1 by selecting any one cell in Column B to see corresponding non duplicates from column D. I have edited the formula #2. It should work for you now and you can download updated file from the same link.

Comment: Excellent! Could you show me more favor and explain the conditions in IF statement and part ROWS($A$1:A1)?

Comment: @FighterJet Great! I have added some explanation. See if it is sufficient for you.

Comment: I appreciate it!